Hibernate : register custom type if certain dialect
With a Hibernate TypeContributor like below (loaded via the Java Service Loader mechanism)
public class MyTypeContributor implements TypeContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        // if Dialect is ... then ... 
    }
}

.. how can I conditionally register types based on the current Dialect?  I cannot see that I have access to Dialect in the method?
Note, I do not want to create a new Dialect.
Oddly, when doing function contributions this information is indeed readily available, but seems not so for type contributions. (comparing FunctionContributions to TypeContributions)
Hibernate version 6.4.
A feabile attempt which replicates what FunctionContributions do in order to expose the Dialect:
public class MyTypeContributor implements TypeContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        Dialect dialect = typeContributions
                  .getTypeConfiguration()
                  .getCurrentBaseSqlTypeIndicators()
                  .getDialect();
    }
}

.. unfortunately this results in a NPE in the getDialect() method.
The below actually works (thanks zforgo), but not sure if we can guarantee that JdbcServices is always available?
public class MyTypeContributor implements TypeContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
       Dialect dialect = serviceRegistry
                  .getService(JdbcServices.class)   // May return null
                  .getDialect();

    }
}


Couldn't you use the ServiceRegistry to obtain the DialectResolver and check the dialect from there?

@M.Deinum. Thanks. Not sure I would know how to use DialectResolver, though. I just want Hibernate to tell me the current (resolved) Dialect.

I strongly suggest you check the Javadoc which classes implement Service and which you can get. There are some involved with dialect like the DialectResolver which should tell you the dialect in use.

@M.Deinum. DialectResolver can resolve (again) provided you give it some information about the database. I want the already resolved Dialect  which I'm sure is available somewhere.

I know what you want, I just pointed you in the direction of Service one of those registered services will hold that information. The easiest way is to slap a debugger on this, check the services in the ServiceRegistry and which information is available.

@M.Deinum. See updated question with an attempt. It seems this information is not meant to be available (by design) ?  Dunno.

Well I think that is because youare configuring the Type indicator isn't available yet.  As mentioned I would check one of the services available in the ServiceRegistry.

JdbcServices has the resolved dialect, which is available by serviceRegistry. Very ugly one liner solution: serviceRegistry.getService(JdbcServices.class).getDialect();

@zforgo.  Appreciated, and yes obtaining JdbcServices works, but it seems brittle to me. I don't know how these Hibernate Services work. Are they instantiated in parallel?  Can I rely on the fact that there will always be a JdbcServices in registry when this stuff runs or am I just accidentally lucky?

There are three kind of service initialized in Hibernate. i.) Bootsrap services (e.g. classloaderSerice or integratorService). ii.) "Dedicated" standard services. These services initiated earlier than other standard services in a hardcoded particular order. iii.) Other standard services registered via SPI.
JdbcServices is "dedicated" so you can be sure that will always be in serviceRegistry.
Here is the list defined in StandardServiceInitiators

@zforgo. Thanks. Unsurprisingly - I should have looked there first - your recommendation is exactly the same as what Hibernate Spatial does. (not that I don't trust your recommendation, of course :-))

Here is a solution based on zforgo's suggestion. It is also the methodology employed by Hibernate Spatial project, so I guess it is aligned with what the Hibernate project developers wants us to do.  :-)
Hibernate Services seem to have a brittle contract in their APIs in particular with respect to when their methods may return null. I'm probably over-doing the checking in the below. Alas, better safe than sorry.
public class MyTypeContributor implements TypeContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
       Dialect dialect = getDialect(serviceRegistry);
    
       // ...

    }

    private Dialect getDialect(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        JdbcServices jdbcServices = serviceRegistry.getService(JdbcServices.class);
        if (jdbcServices == null) {
            // JdbcServices is one of the so-called StandardServices in Hibernate so it should always be present.
            // (see https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/service/StandardServiceInitiators.java)
            // Nevertheless, we make this check.
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: Cannot find a 'JdbcServices' in Hibernate's ServiceRegistry.");
        }
        Dialect dialect = jdbcServices.getDialect();
        if (dialect == null) {
            // Theoretically this can happen if the Hibernate JdbcServices object is not yet configured.
            // Which would mean the JdbcServices does not yet have an associated JdbcEnvironment.
            // In real-life we are guaranteed that it is configured.
            // Nevertheless, we make this check.
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: Hibernate's 'JdbcServices' has no 'JdbcEnvironment'. Dialect cannot be determined.");
        }
        return dialect;
    }

}

